# String input validation in special form

Tags: java, string, validation, char

I'm Trying to except employeenumber XXX-L where x a digit in range 0-9 and L a letter in range of A-M. I'm trying to get this code work. but I can't enter A valid input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class ObjectOrinetPrograming
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter elements: ");
        String employeenumber = input.nextLine();
        while (employeenumber.length() != 5)
        {
            System.out.println("invalid input; lenght, Try again:");
            employeenumber = input.nextLine();
        }


            while (employeenumber.charAt(4) != ('A'|'B'|'C'|'D'|'E'|'F'|'G'|'H'|'I'|'J'|'K'|'L'|'M'))
            {
                System.out.print("invalid input; charrecter match, try again:");
                employeenumber = input.nextLine();
            }


        while (employeenumber.charAt(0) == '-')
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input; form, try again:");
            employeenumber = input.nextLine();
        }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `matches`, which will allow you validate all your inputs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class ObjectOrinetPrograming
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter elements: ");
        String employeenumber = input.nextLine();

        while (!employeenumber.matches("[0-9]{3}-[A-Ma-m]")) {
            System.out.println("invalid input; lenght, Try again:");
            employeenumber = input.nextLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Muzy then the regex would simply be **[0-9]{3}-[A-Ma-m]** to match your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to match input `employeenumber`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter elements: ");
    String employeenumber = input.nextLine();
    while (!employeenumber.matches("[0-9]{3}-[A-M]")) {
        System.out.println("invalid input; lenght, Try again:");
        employeenumber = input.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Your employee id is " + employeenumber);

}
```

Comment: A small correction. the regex should be **[0-9]{3}-[A-M]**

Comment: @iNan thank you so much but i tried it and whenever I input for example : 123-A which is the correct input i still get invalid input.  I think your code except one character as an input what i'm trying to do is excepting 5 characters. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @m4heshd after applying the editing it worked. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Can some one explain why {3} matter and what does it means or do?

Comment: the {3} defines how many characters should the previous stated regex expression should match. XXX means 3 characters right? so it's {3}. Use http://regexr.com/ to practice and get a better understanding about regex. It's a very useful practice.

Comment: @m4heshd thanks a lot so i'm trying to play with it little bit i noticed that if i add another [a-m] beside the [A-M] wont work for small letters i'm trying to figure it out. thanks alot